# How do I only show data from the last seven days or if the date is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to only show the data where my sep_dt date is null or if it's within the last seven days. How would I do this?

```
 SELECT 
     IIF(SEP_DT >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) OR SEP_DT = NULL, 1, 0) AS TERMDATE, 
     * 
 FROM MYTable
```

This isn't working and I don't want the extra `TERMDATE` column. I just need the rest of the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTable WHERE SEP_DT IS NULL OR SEP_DT >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

I assumed you want to actually only return those rows. Also note that when checking for `NULL`, you need to use `IS NULL`, not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * FROM MYTable WHERE SEP_DT IS NULL or DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),SEP_DT) <=7
```